# how to check the month of datenum matlab value?

Tags: matlab

I want to check the month and print the month value in the following code.
please any advise?

```
formatOuttime = 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS';
DateString = '2002/01/01 00:00:00';
datelooping=datenum(DateString,formatOuttime);
for i=1:100
    % do some stuff
    % check the month of the datelooping and print only the month value
    datelooping = datelooping+1;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datevec` to split the date into multiple pieces

```
[year, month, day, hour, minute, second] = datevec(datelooping)
```

You could also pass your `DateString` *directly* to `datevec`

```
[year, month, day, hour, minute, second] = datevec(DateString)
```

Also, if you're on newer versions of MATLAB you can use a [`datetime` object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html)

```
dt = datetime(DateString, 'InputFormat', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:SS');

dt.month
```